# Data and GAM partial effects contradict each other

Tags: generalized-additive-model

I have spatial data and fit a `mgcv` GAM including a number of other covariates to try to identify patterns of occurrence in the presence of other potentially impacting factors. However, the 2D heatmap I get from the model is contradictory to the patterns I see when I only plot our depending variable against the spatial variables. I know that the plots from the GAM are only partial effects, but even then I can't wrap my head around how to interpret this. When I `gam.check()` my model, there are no significances, so my model should be ok as far as I understand it.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Long, y=Lat)) +
  geom_point(aes( fill=y, size=y), shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits=c(0, 100), breaks=seq(0, 100, by=25), colors=heat.colors(999))+
  guides(fill= guide_legend(), size=guide_legend()) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0, 100), breaks=seq(0, 100, by=25))
```

[image: Spatial Data]

```
mod<-gam(y ~ s(Long, Lat) + s(a) + s(b) + s(c) + d, data=df, method = 'REML', select=T)
plot(mod, scheme=2, page=1)
```

[image: GAM partial effects]

covariates a and c are not significant when `anova(mod)`, all others are.

When you compare the first plot with the 2D heatmap (where yellow indicates high, red indicates low), the two provide completely contradicting results, as I do not have high values in my original data in the lower right area that is white/yellow in the GAM heatmap.

Thank you for any help as I'm trying to understand what the model is telling me - or what I'm doing wrong when fitting the model.

**Edit:** *Trying to wrap my head around it.*

Does it mean that the effect of covariate b is so high (effect unit change up to 30 and -20) compared to the spatial effect (-8 to 6ish), that **after** the effect of b is taken into account, the location has a slightly positive effect in that area, hence the low numbers in the annotated area are probably more impacted by b than by spatial patterns?

Comment: I don't totally understand your data here, but you have one very "big" point near your minimum latitude and longitude. This point probably has high leverage and is causing the model to predict high values in that region.

Comment: I have one sample at each point (data from a transect), so that one big point near the minimum is ~75 (single datapoint), while all the other ones moving east/north are zeroes until I meet the next cluster of bigger points (ranging between 25 and 100 with a number of big ones); so if anything, those just above my annotation rectangle should have much more leverage? The legend on the plot is a discrete representation of continuous values. Covariate b is not correlated with Lat/Long in any way.